# Resize & stretch image depending on Web Browser size CSS

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I'm working on a project where I have a few button images that I'd like to automatically resize depending on the browser or screen size.

I've managed to get this in CSS with this code:

```
#nav {
max-width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0%;
right: 0%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: 8;
}

img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

However I'd like it to also stretch horizontally from left to right. The image stick to the left side of the browser but when I increase the width of the browser it results with this:
[image]

I'd like to stretch the images all the way to the right as well if possible.

Comment: Please, make a code fiddle

Answer (score 0):

well, try to add to your `<head>` of the page following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

That should work. And if you want them to the center, just use

```
body {text-align:center;}
```

or `img {margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}`

Comment: I actually already had the meta in my header. Adding the body text algin does move the image to the right but doesn't stretch it.